# ¿Cómo agregar css a un web panel de genexus?

Tags: genexus

Ejemplo si tengo un web panel puedo añadir css a este o mejor dicho alterar su diseño en base un css
ejemplo crear un menú vertical que genexus los hace horizontal
porque agrege html a un web panel y dio bastante errores diciendo que el href no era propiedad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si. Deberias utilizar el objeto UserControl. En dicho editor, vas a poder agregar HTML y CSS. Te dejo información al respecto en el siguiente link:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?39356,Category%3AUser+Control+object